# MATLAB - axes handle get deleted if subplot is created inside class constructor

Tags: matlab, oop, refactoring, matlab-figure

I'm refactoring an existing (working) MATLAB code, in particular I'm extracting a new class from a piece of structured code that creates a figure, and when I do that, I get an error caused by axes of the figure getting deleted (my variable now says it contains a `handle to deleted axes`).

In more detail, the current version of the code does something like this:

```matlab
Overlay = figure
overlayAxes = subplot(1, 2, 1, 'Parent', Overlay)

... (other stuff)

imshow(... other parameters ..., overlayAxes)
```

(I'm mentioning "other stuff" and "other parameters" to clarify the `imshow` line is not directly above the `overlayAxes` assignment, just in case you think I should look for anything in particular before the call to `imshow`)

This works fine. My refactor is consists in moving the creation of `Overlay` to a class (in other words, make it more "OOP-like"). As a first step, I moved it to a class like this:

```matlab
classdef MyGUI < handle

  properties(SetAccess = public)
    Overlay
    overlayAxes
  end

  methods
    function obj = MyGUI()
      obj.Overlay = figure;
      obj.overlayAxes = subplot(1, 2, 1, 'Parent', obj.Overlay);
    end
  end
end
```

And then I referenced this new class where `Overlay` was originally created like this:

```
GUI = MyGUI;
Overlay = GUI.Overlay;
overlayAxes = GUI.overlayAxes;
```

(I made those two variable assignments so I didn't have to change the rest of the code right now - because it references `Overlay` not `GUI.Overlay` - in particular the call to `imshow`)

So, when I do this, the call to `imshow` fails saying:

```
Error using imshow>validateParent (line 375)
HAX must be a valid axes handle.
```

As it turns out, when I debug and inspect `overlayAxes`, it says it contains a `handle to deleted axes`.

I've read some articles explaining that axes get deleted when new figures are created and such, but the *only* change I'm making is converting the figure creation from a local variable to a class property, so I don't feel like is something related to side-effects of calling plot functions again or anything like that, but maybe something about passing by reference, object lifecycle, or something that I'm missing completely, not really sure.

Why are my axes getting deleted? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a destructor in your `MyGUI` class? Any `delete` statement anywhere? A second `MyGUI` object created? The axes get deleted only when (1) closing the figure they're in, (2) creating new axes in that figure (e.g. `subplot` will delete axes if they overlap the new axes), or (3) `delete` is called for that handle.

Comment: No destructor and no second MyGUI object.  New axes ARE being created, but if that's whats causing it, why does it happen only when I refactor it? I mean, my refactor is not adding any new subplot calls, is the exact same code only with part of it moved into a class.

Comment: My best advice is to make a [mcve]. Not to improve your question, but as a debugging tool. Remove stuff from the code until you can’t remove anything else without removing whatever causes this issue. You’ll find your problem in no time. :)

Comment: Sounds like good advice. Since I'm not that experienced with MATLAB I though that maybe there was an obvious reason for this. Thanks!